# Is there a difference between static::class instruction and get_class function?

Tags: php

Is there a difference between `static::class` instruction and `get_class($this)` function?

It seems it does exactly the same thing, but I'm not sure. And sometimes, using PHP, there are some subtle difference between two similar instruction. So, is there a difference in this particular case? (about inheritance, or something like that).

Comment: static::class is faster

There is article about it here: https://belineperspectives.com/2017/03/13/get_classthis-vs-staticclass/

Comment: @DevilaN Ok thanks! You can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static::class` is faster.

There is article about it here: https://belineperspectives.com/2017/03/13/get_classthis-vs-staticclass/